# (Angular 6) Data won't reloaded

Tags: angular, angular6

I use angular 6, I got a problem  after I did update/create an object and reload all the data, it seems the old data were reloaded. I tried to add random number but it won't work as well.

My code as follow:

Inside my Service:

```
 getPayCalendars(): Observable<PayCalendar[]>
 {
   return this.authHttp.get<PayCalendar[]>(this.baseUrl+"payCalendar/all"+"?rand="+Math.random());   
}
```

Inside my component:

```
reloadPayCalendars()
  {
      console.log("RELOAD PAYCALS");
    this.adminSettingService.getPayCalendars().subscribe(
        (result) => {
            this.payCalendars = result; 
            console.log(`Result: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
        }, error => {
            this.alertify.error("Error: Cannot retrive pay calendars");
        }
    );
  }
```

The ReloadCalendars() being called from this method after saving the data from the child component using EventEmitter. I saw the data was changed in DB.

```
updatingData(result: any)
  {        
    this.reloadPayCalendars();
    this.modalRef.hide();
  }

<app-form-paycalendar
            [id]="id"
            [name]="name"
            [frequency]="frequency"
            [payPeriodStartDate]="payPeriodStartDate"
            [payPeriodEndDate]="payPeriodEndDate"
            [nextPaymentDate]="nextPaymentDate"
            (onSubmit)="updatingData($event)"></app-form-paycalendar>
```

I add another button to call reloadPayCalendars() and it got new/updated data.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reloadPayCalendars()"> Reload </button>
```

How to solve this ?

Fyi: backend using Dotnet Core 2.1 with C#.

Edited: 
add component where I use to save/updating data

CHILD Component:

```
save()
  {
    let payCalendar = this.editForm.getRawValue();
    if(payCalendar.id != null){
        this.adminService.updatePayCalendar(payCalendar).subscribe(
            result => {
                payCalendar = result ; 
                this.alertify.success("Update Pay Calendar Successfully");
            }, error => {   
                this.alertify.error(error);
            }
        );
    }else {
        this.adminService.createPayCalendar(payCalendar).subscribe(
            result => {
                payCalendar = result ; 
                this.alertify.success("Update Pay Calendar Successfully");
            }, error => {   
                this.alertify.error(error);
            }
        );
    }
    this.onSubmit.emit({payCalendar: payCalendar});
  }
```

so after this method being called, it will emit to parent and the parent called "updatingData()" above.

Comment: Are both `this.payCalendars` and `result` are `array of objects`?

Comment: Can you show the code where you emit the event after save in the child component ?

Comment: "The ReloadCalendars() being called from this method after saving the data from the child component using EventEmitter". Do you make it in subscribe? else can be happen that the call to get the data happens before ended the call to update

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT yes it is.

Comment: @nightingale2k1 Okay, upto my understanding, even `result` contains the new data, `this.payCalendars` showing only old data, is that the issue?

Comment: @Eliseo yes. i checked the reloadcalendars() being called after create and update but it still got old data. but once i call it again (from button) it load with  new data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I retrive the data while the create/update still in progress in background. so I emit the event just after I finished create/update data.

```
save()
  {
    let payCalendar = this.editForm.getRawValue();
    let opResult: PayCalendar[] ; 
    if(payCalendar.id != null){
        this.adminService.updatePayCalendar(payCalendar).subscribe(
            result => {
                opResult = result;
                this.alertify.success("Update Pay Calendar Successfully");
                **this.onSubmit.emit({payCalendars: opResult});**
            }, error => {   
                this.alertify.error(error);
            }
        );
    }else {
        this.adminService.createPayCalendar(payCalendar).subscribe(
            result => {
                opResult = result;
                this.alertify.success("Create Pay Calendar Successfully");
                **this.onSubmit.emit({payCalendars: opResult});**   
            }, error => {   
                this.alertify.error(error);
            }
        );
    }
  }
```